# Not able to print the filenames in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to create a page in ASP.NET which allows me to see the list of all the files in my Files directory. I want to show only the filenames and allow user to edit the files later.
I have tried this approach here for getting all the filenames and making a datatable then binding that to a gridview. This is my code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row; 
            dt.Columns.Add("FileNames",typeof(string));
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Files");
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles()) {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row["FileNames"] = fi.ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            }
```

I am not able to understand what is the problem here. When I run the page I see an empty GridView with just a header row with the title of FileName but not the names of the files. I have checked there are files in my "Files" folder and using response.write() I am also able to print those names but not able to show it in a gridview.

Here is my Gridview code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
           <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileNames">
                   <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                   </EditItemTemplate>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server"></asp:Label>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
           </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
```

Help me understand this approach and show me the way to print the names in gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues

First this:

```
fi.ToString();
```

But, "fi" is a file info type. You need to use/pull the file name, like this:

```
fi.Name (for file name)
fi.FullName (for full file name)
```

And, you have to as the other poster noted to use Eval() expressions.

You can have the grid automatic create the columns. So, with this markup:

```
<div style="width:45%">
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover">
  </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Then say this code:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack) {
            LoadFiles();
        }
    }


    public void LoadFiles()
    {
        MyTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("File Size", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("File Name", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("FullFile", typeof(string));

        var strFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Scripts");

        DirectoryInfo MyDir = new DirectoryInfo(strFolder);
        FileInfo[] MyFiles = MyDir.GetFiles("*.*");

        foreach (FileInfo MyFile in MyFiles)
        {
            // Dim oneRow As DataRow = MyTable.Rows.Add
            DataRow oneRow;
            oneRow = MyTable.NewRow();

            oneRow["Date"] = MyFile.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString();
            oneRow["File Size"] = (int)(MyFile.Length / (double)1024) + " KB";
            oneRow["File Name"] = MyFile.Name;
            oneRow["FullFile"] = MyFile.FullName;

            MyTable.Rows.Add(oneRow);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = MyTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

OutPut:

[image]

If you want to drop in (have controls) on the gridview, then you can of course use template fields. You can use databoundfield like this:

NOTE the AutoGeneratecolumns = false now

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-hover">
   <Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="File Name" HeaderText="ID" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="FullFile" HeaderText="ID" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="File Size" HeaderText="Size" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
   </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

The output would be much identical to the first example.

Adding a button to the above, we could thus click on a row, get the information.

So, our markup becomes like this say. We don't really have to add the columns if we auto generate, but lets do so, and thus we can control placement of controls (such as our view button).

So, now here is the complete mark-up and code used:

```
       <div style="width:45%">

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

                <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="File Name" HeaderText="File Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FullFile" HeaderText="Full File" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="File Size" HeaderText="Size" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View"
                                CommandName="Select"
                                OnClick="cmdView_Click"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
             </asp:GridView>

        </div>
```

Now our code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            LoadFiles();
        }
    }

    public void LoadFiles()
    {
        DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();

        MyTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("File Size", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("File Name", typeof(string));
        MyTable.Columns.Add("FullFile", typeof(string));

        var strFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Scripts");

        DirectoryInfo MyDir = new DirectoryInfo(strFolder);
        FileInfo[] MyFiles = MyDir.GetFiles("*.*");

        foreach (FileInfo MyFile in MyFiles)
        {
            // Dim oneRow As DataRow = MyTable.Rows.Add
            DataRow oneRow;
            oneRow = MyTable.NewRow();

            oneRow["Date"] = MyFile.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString();
            oneRow["File Size"] = (int)(MyFile.Length / (double)1024) + " KB";
            oneRow["File Name"] = MyFile.Name;
            oneRow["FullFile"] = MyFile.FullName;

            MyTable.Rows.Add(oneRow);
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = MyTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void cmdView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gvR = (GridViewRow)btn.Parent.Parent;

        Response.Write("<h2> File name selected = " + gvR.Cells[2].Text + "</h2>");

    }
```

And now our output:

And note how we can now click on any row. I clicked on 2nd row for this screen shot:

[image]

Note the cool trick to get the grid row with one click - don't hve to use data item index change and all that non-sense.

Just drag + drop in the asp .net button into grid view (inside the template), and then add the click event as I did.

FYI: Note that you MUST include the CommandName="Select". This will cause the row index position to change - if you don't include that, then our simple button click will NOT get/see the current grid row selected. So, don't forget that all important command. Do note that using CommandName="Select" WILL ALSO trigger the GV index changed event, but this way we just use the simple button event - and thus don't care much.

***Edit ------------------------***

there is some question about me having used btn.parent.Parent to get the slected grid row. The issue is that I just felt like using the button click event, but we did not have to.

The above will STILL work, but I suggest REMOVE the button click event stub, and place the code here:

```
   protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvR = GridView1.SelectedRow;

        Response.Write("<h2> File name selected = " + gvR.Cells[2].Text + "</h2>");

    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for helping me. There is just one thing if you can explain (or guide me to a resource which can help me to understand) what is the code on onClick event means. Especially parent.parent

Comment: I just like to drop in a button, and then have click event with code behind for that button. I just think this is less hassle. When you click any control with events, then "sender = ALWAYS the control you clicked on". The first parent to button I think "grid row cell, and then next parent step up is the grid row - which we want.  Because of CommandName = "select" then grid view SelectedIndexChanged event will fire. You probably would be less confused and better to use the Gridview event SelectedIndexChanged. Code would be identical to button code without having to get/use sender and .parent.

Comment: So try doing this with Gridview selected index changed. I might even edit this post to remove that confusing part.

Comment: see my new edit - I show how to remove the button click code - just put your code as per the final edit here - they both will work the same, but for a more general code approach - use the selected index changed event as my edit shows. (you thus will NOT have ANY event stub code for the button - but the magic CommandName="Select" will still fire the index change event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the fieldname to bind the control, something like this -

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FileName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
```